# C merge two linked lists

Tags: c, linked-list

I'm trying to copy the contents of two linked lists in one such that one element at a time (from each of the linked lists) is copied.

So, if I have: `list1 = [1,2,3]`, and `list2 = [4,5,6]`, the `result = [1,4,2,5,3,6]`.
If one list is shorter than the other then the remaining nodes are appended at the end of the resulted list.

Here's my code, which works with a slight bug: it creates an extra node at the end (which I do not want).

```
node *list_copy(node *list1, node *list2) 
{
    node *mylist = newnode(); 
    node *head = mylist;

    while (list1 != NULL || list2 != NULL) {        

        if (list1 != NULL) {
            mylist->data = list1->data;
            mylist->next = newnode();
            mylist = mylist->next;
        
            list1 = list1->next;
        } 
        if (list2 != NULL) { 
            mylist->data = list2->data;
                mylist->next = newnode();
            mylist = mylist->next;

            list2 = list2->next;
        }

    }
    return head;
}
```

How do I modify it such that it doesn't create the last node?

#### Example input:

```
List1 = [1,2,3], List2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6], Result = [1,1,2,2,3,3,4,5,6,0];
```

Comment: if it's node, why you name it as "mylist"? making good names for your variables is a very important habit

Comment: @xvatar What? [15 chars]

Answer (score 2):

Don't do the merge in one while block, it makes your code harder to read. Functionally decompose the list copy into another function and call it twice.

You're doing a newnode before the loop and then newnode after adding the current item. How about...

```
node *mylist; 
node *head;

while (listItem != null) {

    if(head == null) {        
       mylist = newnode();
       head = myList;
    }
    else {
       mylist->next = newnode();
       mylist = mylist->next;
    }


    mylist->data = listItem->data;    
    listItem = listItem->next;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should get you going. Note that it seems that in your example, the output needs to be sorted. You can handle that as part of the list merge operation by adding some extra tests, but I'll leave that as an exercise (not sure if sorted result was part of your requirement).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <queue>
#include <deque>
#include <set>
#include <map>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cctype>
#include <cassert>
#include <cmath>
#include <complex>
#include <stack>
using namespace std;

struct node {
  int data;
  node* next;
};

node *list_copy(node *list1, node *list2) 
{
    node *mylist;
    node *head;

    mylist = NULL;
    while (list1 != NULL || list2 != NULL) {        

        if (mylist == NULL) {
            mylist = new node;
            head = mylist;
        }
        else {
            mylist->next = new node;
            mylist = mylist->next;
        }

        if (list1 != NULL) {
            mylist->data = list1->data;
            list1 = list1->next;
        } 
        else if (list2 != NULL) { 
            mylist->data = list2->data;
            list2 = list2->next;
        }

    }
    return head;
}   

node* addnode(node* list, int val) {
  if (list == NULL)
    list = new node;
  else {
    list->next = new node;
    list = list->next;
  }
  list->data = val;
  return list;
}

int main() {
  node* list1;
  node* head1;
  node* list2;
  node* head2;

  list1 = NULL;
  list2 = NULL;

  list1 = addnode(list1,1);
  head1 = list1;
  list1 = addnode(list1,2);
  list1 = addnode(list1,3);

  list2 = addnode(list2,1);
  head2 = list2;
  list2 = addnode(list2,2);
  list2 = addnode(list2,3);
  list2 = addnode(list2,4);
  list2 = addnode(list2,5);
  list2 = addnode(list2,6);

  node* m = list_copy(head1,head2);
  while(m != NULL) {
    cout<<(m->data)<<endl;
    m = m->next;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
---------- Capture Output ----------
> "c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe" /c C:\temp\temp.exe
1
2
3
1
2
3
4
5
6

> Terminated with exit code 0.
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is your code with little modifications. Hope this will be helpful to you

```
node *list_copy(node *list1, node *list2) 
{
    node *mylist = NULL; 
    node *head = NULL;

    while (list1 != NULL || list2 != NULL) {        

        if (head == NULL)
        {
            mylist = newnode();
            head = mylist;
        }  
        else
        {
            mylist->next = newnode();
            mylist = mylist->next;                 
        } 

        if (list1 != NULL) {
            mylist->data = list1->data;   
            list1 = list1->next;
        } 
        if (list2 != NULL) { 
            mylist->data = list2->data;
            list2 = list2->next;
        }
        mylist->next = NULL;
    }
    return head;
}
```

Comment: If both list1 and list2 are NOT null, then your code will only add the data from list2->data (e.g. the mylist->data = list2->data will overwrite the list1->data value you set in the previous if statement). Also, you are leaving an unfreed memory reference by allocating mylist->next and then just setting it to NULL.

Comment: yes its a mistake, i need to modify my code

Answer (score -1):

Update: it appears the OP wants *copies* of the list.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
struct llist * llist_merge_and_dup(struct llist *one, struct llist *two, int (*cmp)(struct llist *l, struct llist *r) );
struct llist *llist_dup(struct llist *org);

struct llist *llist_dup(struct llist *org)
{
struct llist *new;
new = malloc (sizeof *new);
if (!new) return NULL;
memcpy (new, org, sizeof new);
new->next = NULL;
return new;
}

struct llist * llist_merge_and_dup(struct llist *one, struct llist *two, int (*cmp)(struct llist *l, struct llist *r) )
{
struct llist *result, **tail;

for (result=NULL, tail = &result; one && two; tail = &(*tail)->next ) {
        if (cmp(one,two) <=0) { *tail = llist_dup(one); one=one->next; }
        else { *tail = llist_dup(two); two=two->next; }
        }

for( ; one; one = one->next) {
        *tail = llist_dup(one);
        }

for( ; two; two = two->next) {
        *tail = llist_dup(two);
        }
return result;
                                                                                              }
```